# Modify QToolBar area detection

Tags: c++, qt

When I move a QToolBar in my main window, the main window detects when the QToolBar can be dropped in an area. The area is detected slighlty too early for me so I would like to know if there is a way to modify that.

[image: The area (blue rect) is detected too early]